# Import Testresults to HP ALM with Excel AddIn

Tags: excel, hp-alm

My question is, as mentioned in the headline, is it possible to import testresult from Excel into HP ALM?

Explanation:

My current task is to import all Testcases/results from Word/Excel to HP ALM. It is necessary for me to import Testresults too, because of an internal audit.

After searching the HP Plattform I stumbled across this question:

[HP Forum](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/Import-Test-results-from-excel-to-Quality-center/td-p/947595/page/2)

In this thread they say it is solvable by a macro but I don't have the permission to write and execute my own Macros.

For the record: I have limited rights and function in my HP ALM through the company policies. Every change like macros or something else has to be reported to the Testmanagementboard.

I appreciate every advice :)

Thanks in advance 
Robert

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, the **answer is to inform your superiors that their choices are for you or someone else to spend some huge amount of time manually entering the results** (assuming you have been able to import test cases), **or** they can have **someone with the proper programming knowledge uses the HP API to generate the import**(which also could be a huge amount of time depending on how much data mangling and programming you need).

If this is a one-time data entry, there's a fair chance someone is going to find themselves manually entering a lot of data.

If you're going to need to import test result data on a regular basis, you have a better chance that programming resources will be available.

Regardless, at this point the decision needs to be made by someone further up the hierarchy than you because you don't have the access to make the decision.